# Does a Control Weather effect and Gust of Wind effect stack or not, and why?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, magic, psionics, weather

Does a *Control Weather* type effect and *Gust of Wind* type effect stack or not for purposes of total wind speed, and why?

One or more of these effects may arise from items or effects of psionic and/or magic nature, as well as possibly Supernatural abilities.

Comment: *Control Weather* rather than *Control Winds* - just because of availability?

Answer (score 1):

## YES it could stack but with some limitations and in some instances it might just overlap

After reading the 2 spells you mentioned (*control weather* and *Gust of Wind*) and the rules on wind effects (*and Control Winds*) I'll stick to them the most I can and I'll apply logic for what is not covered.

**Perhaps just using *Control Winds* (thank you @Miniman), would be better for you and if you have the appropriate caster level (or emulate it) it would just be easier for you, it will combine well with *control weather* if you're lucky enough to have the right season or the appropriate climate. *Control weather* being a higher level spell might just justify the ability to control the wind a bit more than just what is shown in the description but your DM will have to explain how he rules it.**

- Let's start with the rules on Wind effects (see Table Wind effects from the [SRD](https://www.d20srd.org/srd/weather.htm)) :

  We can see that the stronger the wind Force (directly affected by wind speed) is, the stronger is the effect on creatures and the environment.
- The Spell *Control Weather* states:

  > **Season**:  Possible Weather
  >
  > **Spring**:   **Tornado**, thunderstorm, sleet storm, or hot weather
  >
  > **Summer**:   Torrential rain, heat wave, or hailstorm
  >
  > **Autumn**:   Hot or cold weather, fog, or sleet
  >
  > **Winter**:   Frigid cold, blizzard, or thaw
  >
  > **Late winter**:  **Hurricane-force winds** or early spring (coastal area)
  >
  > You change the weather in the local area. It takes 10 minutes to cast
  >   the spell and an additional 10 minutes for the effects to manifest.
  >   You can call forth weather **appropriate to the climate and season of
  >   the area you are in**.
  >
  > You control the **general tendencies of the weather, such as the
  >   direction and intensity of the wind**. **You cannot control specific
  >   applications** of the weather—where lightning strikes, for example, or
  >   **the exact path of a tornado**. When you select a certain weather
  >   condition to occur, the weather assumes that condition 10 minutes
  >   later (changing gradually, not abruptly). The weather continues as you
  >   left it for the duration, or until you use a standard action to
  >   designate a new kind of weather (which fully manifests itself 10
  >   minutes later). Contradictory conditions are not possible
  >   simultaneously.
  >
  > **Control weather can do away with atmospheric phenomena** (naturally occurring **or otherwise**) as well as create them.
  >
  > A druid casting this spell doubles the duration and affects a circle with a 3-mile radius.

  I noticed some key words that limits you how it can be done, and terms used directly in the wind effects rules. I figured that **unless the season is similar to spring (climate might allow it even if it's not spring) you can't really make tornadoes** in those area and it might be **because the spell *control winds* already exist probably for that very reason** (but it's a weaker spell so ask your DM how ''intensity of the wind'' should be interpreted because you might not be able to control the strength of the wind as you wish depending on the season/climate). **Since you can control the direction of the wind you could probably make it stack with *Gust of Wind*!**

  **Furthermore** it says that it **CAN** do away atmospheric phenomena wich means you can let/remove things that were there before (such as a permanent *Gust of Wind* (probably only temporarily)) there, so if a tornado is happening right now you can perhaps let it there according to the spell description if let's say you'd want to calm the weather in all the region but you would not want the tornado (blowing your opponents away) further away to stop.
- Now let's see the spell *Gust of Wind* it states:

  > This spell creates a severe **blast** of air (**approximately 50 mph**) that originates from you, affecting all creatures in its path. (...)

  Note that it also states that the effect is a:

  > Line-shaped gust of severe wind emanating out from you to the extreme
  >   of the range

  **Take note that this is Just a level 2 spell.**
  (can be made permanent)
- Now let's check the spell *Control Winds* (you should use this as @Miniman points out if it's available, or you could use *Limited Wish* to ''cast'' it) it states:

  > You alter wind force in the area surrounding you. You can make the
  >   wind blow in a **certain direction or manner, increase its strength, or
  >   decrease its strength**. The **new** wind direction and strength persist
  >   until the spell ends or until you choose to alter your handiwork,
  >   which requires concentration. You may create an “eye” of calm air up
  >   to 80 feet in diameter at the center of the area if you so desire, and
  >   you may choose to limit the area to any cylindrical area less than
  >   your full limit.
  >
  > **Wind Direction**: You may choose one of four basic wind patterns to
  >   function over the spell's area.
  >
  > **A downdraft blows** from the center outward in equal strength in all
  >   directions.
  >
  > **An updraft blows** from the outer edges in toward the center
  >   in equal strength from all directions, veering upward before impinging
  >   on the eye in the center.
  >
  > **A rotation** causes the winds to circle the
  >   center in clockwise or counterclockwise fashion.
  >
  > **A blast** simply causes
  >   the winds to blow in one direction across the entire area from one
  >   side to the other.
  >
  > *Wind Strength*
  >
  > For every three caster levels, you
  >   can increase or decrease wind strength by one level. Each round on
  >   your turn, a creature in the wind must make a Fortitude save or suffer
  >   the effect of being in the windy area.
  >
  > **Strong winds** (21+ mph) make sailing difficult.
  >
  > **A severe wind** (31+ mph) causes minor ship and building damage.
  >
  > **A windstorm** (51+ mph) drives most flying creatures from the skies,
  >   uproots small trees, knocks down light wooden structures, tears off
  >   roofs, and endangers ships.
  >
  > **Hurricane force winds** (75+ mph) destroy wooden buildings, sometimes
  >   uproot even large trees, and cause most ships to founder.
  >
  > **A tornado** (175+ mph) destroys all nonfortified buildings and often
  >   uproots large trees.

  The important thing to observe here (Assuming a Druid) is that: you can create a tornado from ''calm'' winds (<21mph) but requires 15 caster level, (even though *Control Winds* is a level 5 spell and that *Control Weather* is a level 7 spell at level 13 you can cast *Control weather* but not do so) so with this observation you might not be able to do as you please with the wind force after all... Ask your DM once again how he will rule *Control Weather*. (see last point in the conclusion for a way around this via RAW)

## In Conclusion

- So with the wording here, I guess if you would for example create a
  *Gust of Wind* of 50mph in area already containing a ''Line-shaped gust of severe wind'' of 50mph (such as a blast from control wind or natural wind in a corridor)  I think **they would just overlap**.
  However if you were to use *control winds* (or if the wind in the
  area have a different wind pattern than *Gust of Wind* (with *Control
  weather* or happening naturally)) to create a different wind pattern,
  I would allow it to **combine/cancel with each other and augment/decrease the wind
  force**, because that's how wind works for tornadoes in some way, I'm
  not an expert in any way, but that's a clever way to use the rules in
  my opinion, but since I'm not your DM, I can't say it will truly
  work, in this case by RAW it's hard to come with a truthful answer,
  but I think I figured out some limitations with the *Control Weather*
  spell as shown in the description that you might agree...or disagree because that's a more powerful spell after all!
- As *Control Winds* (**Weaker spell than *Control Weather***) Shows, you need 3 caster level for each level of
  wind force you want to increase/decrease, so using another spell to
  boost an effect could be justified to your DM, but he might rule that
  it would just be too powerful to your level as well, some tests could
  be done perhaps to see the effects in the campaign. (Note:15 caster levels to raise from ''calm wind'' to Tornado (and vice versa) are required).

  - If your DM rules that you can't control the wind force as you want with *control weather* here's a way to trick the rules a bit (Assume a lvl 13 druid):It would be impossible in a calm day in winter to use *Control Winds* and make a tornado (15 caster level required normally **so *Control weather* might not permit it at lvl 13 or simply not at all**) Let's say it's Winter or a climate where Tornadoes never happens and only Hurricane-force winds are possible, you then cast *Control Weather* to make Hurricane-force winds happen, then with *Control Winds* you can just augment it to a tornado easily (only 3 caster levels required to do so but the minimum to cast it is 9 anyways).